# measure data usage of the c# application

Tags: sql-server

I have c# application that is communicating frequently with the MS SQL server that is on remote server. The application runs almost 24/7. I have noticed that in 1 month the data usage is 20 GB which i find too much for SQL queries.
How can i calculate how much would be data usage by reading from DB e.g. only Int32 column? I guess minimum each query would be 4 byte, but there is likely some overhead for establishing communication with the remote server? It is hard for me to imagine how could SQL queries spend around 800MB per day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> . How can i calculate how much would be data usage by reading from DB e.g. only Int32 column?

Enable [enable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.statisticsenabled?view=netframework-4.8) .NET's SqlConnection statistics, and then examine the results with [SqlConnection.RetrieveStatistics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.retrievestatistics?view=netframework-4.8).